# length must be at least one error

Tags: java

```
import android.graphics.Color;

import java.util.Random;

public class Colors {
    public String[] mColors = {
            "#39add1", // light blue
            "#3079ab", // dark blue

    };
    public int getColor(){
        String colors="";
        //Randomly select
        Random ran = new Random();
        int random = ran.nextInt(mColors.length);
        colors= mColors[random];
        return Color.parseColor(colors);

    }

}
```

It gives me an error in the return line parameter, colors. It says length must be at least one (was 0). How do I fix this problem? Why is it saying that?

Comment: this code is fine, show your `Color.parseColor` code

Comment: And please show the *exact* error, ideally as a stack trace.

Comment: @ka4eli See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor(java.lang.String)

Comment: is there any other point in the `Colors` class that alters the contents of `mColors` (perhaps the constructor, or a "setter" method)? Can you show us the snippet that calls the `getColor()` method? What is the output of `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mColors));` just before the return statement?

Comment: the project worked after I "suppressed the inspection for the project".